# Custom Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption

I am making a custom encryption/decryption software. I have already wrote the code:

```
    public int CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(string Text)
    {
        int Count = 0;
        foreach (char x in Text)
        {
            Count++;
        }
        return Count - 1;
    }

    public int CountCharInString(string Text)
    {
        int Count = 0;
        foreach (char x in Text)
        {
            Count++;
        }
        return Count;
    }
    public string Encrypt(string Key, string PlainText)
    {
        int[] TempKey = new int[CountCharInString(Key)];
        int[] TempText = new int[CountCharInString(PlainText)];
        int[] EncryptedInt = new int[CountCharInString(PlainText)];
        char[] EncryptedChar = new char[CountCharInString(PlainText)];
        for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key); i++)
        {
            TempKey[i] = (int)Key[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(PlainText); i++)
        {
            TempText[i] = (int)PlainText[i];
        }
        int Index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(PlainText); i++)
        {
            if (Index == CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key))
            {
                Index = 0;
            }
            EncryptedInt[i] = TempKey[Index] + TempText[i];
            Index++;
            EncryptedChar[i] = (char)EncryptedInt[i];
        }
        return new string(EncryptedChar);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string Key, string EncryptedText)
    {
        int[] TempKey = new int[CountCharInString(Key)];
        int[] TempText = new int[CountCharInString(EncryptedText)];
        int[] DecryptedInt = new int[CountCharInString(EncryptedText)];
        char[] DecryptedChar = new char[CountCharInString(EncryptedText)];
        for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key); i++)
        {
            TempKey[i] = (int)Key[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(EncryptedText); i++)
        {
            TempText[i] = (int)EncryptedText[i];
        }
        int Index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(EncryptedText); i++)
        {
            if (Index == CountCharInStringAccordingToArray(Key))
            {
                Index = 0;
            }
            DecryptedInt[i] = TempText[i] - TempKey[Index];
            Index++;
            DecryptedChar[i] = (char)DecryptedInt[i];
        }
        return new string(DecryptedChar);
    }
```

But my problem is that when I encrypt:

Key = abc123

PlainText = Hello everyone, how are you guys doing?

Encryption Result:§ÑÕ

And when I decrypt:

Key = abc123

EncryptedText = §ÑÕ

Decryption Result: ﾟﾞﾝￆ

When I decrypt the encrypted text, I get something totally different from "Hello everyone, how are you guys doing?".

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to create custom encryption? Using existing encryption algorithms properly is hard enough already, why are you making it much harder for yourself? Or is this a learning exercise?

Comment: strings have a `Length` property.

Comment: As svick says, unless this is a learning exercise the best advice we can give you is **do not make your own encryption**. The best thing to do is *don't use encryption* in the first place; many people use encryption for tasks that it is completely unsuited for. If you do have to use it, use an encryption toolkit that was built by professionals.

Comment: To solve your actual problem: start with a single-character string and the smallest possible key, and trace through your program one line at a time, verifying at each line that the result is *exactly what you compute by hand it should be*. You will soon find the bug.

Comment: Also, the result of encryption should be a collection of *bytes*, not a collection of *characters*. (Unless you're actually using character-based encryption, like Caesar cipher.)

Comment: Make sure that when encrypting and decrypting, you don't just do the same operations, but decrypting does them in the reverse order. Once you've confirmed that, verify that each operation's counterpart in decrypting, if you only do that operation, encrypts and decrypts successfully. That way you'll find out what components are flawed.

Comment: I want to make a custom encryption because I can't understand how the existing encryption algorithms works, also making a custom one so I could take full control. It's a challenge too. :)

Comment: I recommend you use something like [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64); it doesn't encrypt anything, but it's easy to understand and looks encrypted to an innocent onlooker, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Consider implementing something that is much safe and semi useful - Base32 encoding is not part of .Net but may be useful to construct urls and file names. You'll get much safer to talk subject that have about the same complexity of code.

Comment: Encryption libraries are complicated to use because the problem space is difficult. People often imagine encryption to be this magic process that magically makes their data safe. This could not be further from the truth. Just figuring out the correct encryption scheme is difficult as you have to balance who should have access to the data and what sort of access.

Comment: Your code works like crypto from the pre-computer age, and even then there were much stronger algos. Modern crypto works completely differently.

Comment: @Dan Figuring out how to use .NETs crypto libraries correctly is pretty hard. Even most of those writing tutorials about it didn't manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

While the others have said a lot already, the actual problem in your code is the use of the property "Text" in your Encrypt and Decrypt functions. In your function headers, the input arguments are "PlainText" and "EncryptedText" but in the body of your function you are trying to refer to them using "Text". The Text property belongs to the main window of your program - both your Encrypt and Decrypt functions are performing their operations on that text regardless of the actual text you put into them.

As a general rule in C#, try not to have your local variables begin with capital letters. Names starting with capital letters are usually reserved for properties and methods. As you can see from the error in your code, you referenced a completely different property than the variable you were expecting. Adopting a naming scheme such as camel case will avoid these kinds of unintentional references and allow the debugger to tell you when you've made this sort of mistake.

Comment: Update: It still doesn't work for some reasons. The decrypting part always seems to go wrong (or the encrypting part).